# Python list print - order and space for missing values in either list

Tags: python-3.x, list, lambda

Let's suppose I have the following two lists:

```
foo = [A,B,C,D,Z,G]
bar = [A,C,D,E,F,G,X,H]
```

I want to print them out as following:

```
|  A  |  A  |
|  B  |     |
|  C  |  C  |
|  D  |  D  |
|  z  |     |
|     |  E  |
|     |  F  |
|  G  |  G  |
|     |  x  |
|     |  H  |
```

I'm doing a very complicated if else, just want to know if you guys have a simpler way of doing this. TIA

Comment: do you need final result in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution

```
foo = ["A","B","C","D","Z","G"]
bar = ["A","C","D","E","F","G","X","H"]
all_list = sorted(list(set(foo+bar)))
res = ""
for i in all_list:
    left = i if i in foo else " "
    right = i if i in bar else " "
    res += "|"+left+"|"+right +"|" + "\n"
print(res)
```

output

```
|A|A|
|B| |
|C|C|
|D|D|
| |E|
| |F|
|G|G|
| |H|
| |X|
|Z| |
```